# bettercap http https proxy no CA

Tags: http, ssl, https, proxy, ca

I am currently working on a proxy. The software I use is 'Bettercap'. Personally, I like squid more, because its able to handle caching, and that makes things way faster.

The goal is to let **https traffic** pass through the proxy with no change, but inject a little js snippet in **http** content.
It should not be that complicated so **SSl stripp** and **HSTS Bypass** is not a must-have. Am I able to let the cache never expire, so that even when the proxy is turned off the script works?

How do I split the traffic up, so that no **CA** must be installed?
Alternatively, I could build a landing page to require the user to install the CA...
**Thanks for your help!**